# Jittery behaviour when scrolling within bounds

Tags: android, canvas, scroll, touch-event

After a long hiatus, I've come back to a project I was working on last year which involves trying to scroll around a grid. I achieve this by handling the `ACTION_MOVE` case in the `onTouchEvent` of a custom class extending `Canvas`, and it all works very smoothly.

My problem is that I only want the user to be able to scroll the canvas so far, and after some boundaries have been reached to stop the scrolling. So I tried this:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

pointerIndex = event.findPointerIndex(activePointerId);
pointer.set(event.getX(pointerIndex),event.getY(pointerIndex));

//compute how far the finger slid
float dx = pointer.x - start.x;
float dy = pointer.y - start.y;

//adjust displacement values so that we don't go beyond the bounds 
//determined by the (transformed) corners
matrix.mapPoints(transformedCorners,originalCorners);

//horizontal distance between left corners
float maxHorDisp = originalCorners[0] - transformedCorners[0]; 

//horizontal distance between right corners
float minHorDisp = originalCorners[2] - transformedCorners[2];

//vertical distance between top corners
float maxVertDisp = originalCorners[1] - transformedCorners[1];

//vertical distance between bottom corners
float minVertDisp = originalCorners[3] - transformedCorners[3];

dx = Math.max(minHorDisp,Math.min(maxHorDisp,dx);
dy = Math.max(minVertDisp, Math.min(maxVertDisp,dy);

//Only move if finger slides far away enough from the starting point
distance = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);

if((mode == DRAG) && (distance > 25)){

    dspl.set(dx, dy);
    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
    matrix.postTranslate(dspl.x, dspl.y);
    invalidate();
}
```

Here, `originalCorners` is just a float array keeping track of the corners of the screen before any transformations have occurred and is initialized like this:

```
viewWidth = w;
viewHeight = h;
originalCorners[0] = 0;
originalCorners[1] = 0;
originalCorners[2] = w;
originalCorners[3] = h;
```

and `transformedCorners` is another float array keeping track of where the corners are after any translations or zooming has occurred. It is always updated as follows:
`matrix.mapPoints(transformedCorners,originalCorners);`

This sort of achieves my goal of stopping scrolling past the boundaries, but the grid starts to jitter like crazy when sliding too far in any direction (before the boundaries are reached). You are initially stopped too early, but if you keep sliding in the same direction you can eventually get the edge of the grid to coincide with the edge of the screen.

I've tried a few things (like adding a little buffer value to xMax, yMax and subtracting it from xMin,yMin) but nothing has worked.

So how do I get rid of the jitter and also make it so you can get the edge of the grid to coincide with the edge of the screen with one smooth swipe?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Pan only when the difference between old and new avles exceeds the threshold value :)

Comment: This is already done: I only change the matrix if  `mode==DRAG` and `distance > 25`, where `distance` is the threshold value. Also keep in mind, everything works smoothly with the bounds removed.